# redirecting a page in php

Tags: php

I managed to create a search bar that searches my forum,it searches the categories table then displays the results,however i want to make a link that redirects me to that result found ,for example i search for a category called business and it displays the result but i want the result to have a link such that when i click it it redirects me to that category
but i am getting an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\captcha2\tut.php on line 43
```

my code on line 43 is

```
<td>'.$category_title.="<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a>"'</td> 
                    </tr>'
```

and this is my search bar code

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){ //form submitted, clicked Submit Search 
    $query = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query'])); //try to prevent sql injections
    if(!$query){ //not enterered a query 
        echo 'You must enter a search query!'; 
    }else{ 

        $table = 'categories'; //the table you want to search 
        $row = 'category_title'; //the row in which you want to search 

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$table."` WHERE `".$row."` LIKE '%".$query."%'"); //search query 
        if($sql){ //no errors 
            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){ //No results found. 
                echo 'No results were found for <strong>'.$query.'</strong>'; 
            }else{ //one or more results have been found 
                echo 'We have found <strong>'.mysql_num_rows($sql).'</strong> for <strong>'.$query.'</strong>.<br><br> 
                <table> 
                    <tbody> 
                        <tr> 

                            <td><strong>category_title</strong></td> 
                        </tr>'; 
                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ //get data of every user where their category_title is like the $query string 

                    $category_title = $r["category_title"]; 
                    //lets put the part they searched in bold. 
                    $category_title = str_ireplace($query, '<strong>'.$query.'</strong>', $category_title); 
                    //lets put the part they searched in bold. 
                    echo '<tr> 

                <td>'.$category_title.="<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a>"'</td> 
                    </tr>'; 
                } 
                echo '</tbody></table>'; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            echo 'Sorry, an MySQL error occurred:<br><br>'.mysql_error(); //an error occurred, so echo it 
        } 
    } 
}else{ //not clicked Submit Search, so echo the form 
    echo '<h3>Search</h3> 
    <br><br> 
    <form method="post"> 
        <label for="q"></label> <input type="text" size="100" name="query" id="q" value="m0nsta."> 
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"> 
    </form>'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Get an editor with at least the most basic minimal just-enough-to-use syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the = sign, and an extra quotation

```
<td>'.$category_title.="<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a>"'</td> 
                </tr>'
```

Should be

```
<td>'.$category_title."<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a></td> 
                </tr>"
```

Comment: Hi Bryan i think ending part of your suggestion has a small typing mistake? the last string starts with a double quote and ends on a single one

Answer (score 1):

```
."</font></a>"'</td> 
                    </tr>';
```

This should end with a double quotation mark and not single  like

```
echo '<tr> <td>'.$category_title."<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."' class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\forum part two\index.php on line 75

Notice: Undefined variable: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\forum part two\index.php on line 75

Notice: Undefined variable: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\forum part two\index.php on line 75 thats im getting if i use your code

Comment: That means those variables that you are using there are not defined before, but it also means that the syntax error is resolved

Comment: As far as i can see in your code those 3 variables that you have used in this statement are not defined. $title,$id,$description

Answer (score 0):

**USE**

```
 <td>'.$category_title."=<a href='view_category.php?cid=".$id."'      class='cat_links'>".$title." - <font size='-1'>".$description."</font></a></td> 
                    </tr>'";
```

Make use of eclipse IDE as a habit, it will really help you to avoid such errors

Comment: or Netbeans or anything else, but an IDE. Your answer is not that well anyway (remove `=`).